# Jenkins Pipeline API

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `csp` script, with which I want to shallow recursive clone from git with submodules. The normal invocation in a job would look something like:

```
git {
  remote {
    credentials('5193fea5-344e-4432-fb7a-df45319469bf')
    url('git@git.foo/bar.git')
  }
  shallowClone()
  extensions {
    cloneOptions {
      shallow(true)
    }
    submoduleOptions {
      recursive(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I do the same in `csp`, it complains about `url` being a closure.
Looking at https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/ there seems to be a different API from the normal job one.

So I am confused. Are there multiple APIs now? Can I use the "usual" approach at all in csp?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can extract the attributes straight from Plugin Source code. Not very convenient but there seem no better solution currently...